# Adding an image above each li within my nav

Tags: html, css

How can I add an image above the text in my navigation. It should be displayed ABOVE the text.

**My HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="whoweare"><a href="#">who we are</a></li>
  <li class="services"><a href="#">services</a></li>
  <li class="contact"><a href="#">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**My CSS**

```
ul.nav {
  list-style: none; 
  border-top: 20px solid #FFF; 
}

ul.nav li {
  float: left;
  text-align:center;
  width: 23%;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "above"? Floating over the text so the image covers the text? Vertically over the text so the image appears higher on the screen than the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/YxkPz/

If you need the image to be clickable simply put it INSIDE the `<a>` tag

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/YxkPz/1/

The image needs to `display:block;`

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="whoweare"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/50/sports/9/"><a href="#">who we are</a></li>
  <li class="services"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/50/sports/4/"><a href="#">services</a></li>
  <li class="contact"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/50/sports/1/"><a href="#">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.nav {
  list-style: none; 
  border-top: 20px solid #FFF; 
}

ul.nav li {
  float: left;
  text-align:center;
  width: 23%;

}
ul.nav li img{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: my image is still sliding to the side of it does my image have to be a certain size ?

Comment: my images a small about 40x40 px

Comment: no.. display:block will put the stuff behind it in a new line.. (look at the fiddles I provided). If you are having problems please make a fiddle so we can see it.

Comment: my image block the img is being displayed in front of the text

Comment: below is my code it is exactly the same:
ul.nav {
 list-style: none;
 border-top: 20px solid #FFF;
 
}
ul.nav li {
 float: left;
 text-align:center;
 width: 23%;
}

ul.nav li img{
  display:block;
}

Comment: sorry, I can't help you unless you provide a fiddle for this.

Comment: understood I found the problem though it seems my html is  giving the trouble thanks though

Comment: I have added the actual page to a website www.webapp-testing.com/rethink to show the error I am getting. I am also trying to get the menu to be inline with the logo

Answer (score 0):

u can also add image to link using the background-image:url('paper.gif'); nad set the text-indent:-9999px;

```
.whoweare{
      background-image:url('image_path');
      text-indent:-9999px;
     }
 .services{
       background-image:url('image_path');
      text-indent:-9999px;
     }
 .contact{
      background-image:url('image_path');
      text-indent:-9999px;
     }
```